# SQL queries, how to select

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

```
Table: branch
Fields:
id int (pk)
name varchar
```

```
Table: person
Fields:
id int (pk)
office_id int not null
chief_id int
name varchar
wage float
```

1. I want to select all people, who get paid more than their direct chiefs

```
SELECT * 
FROM `person` 
WHERE `id`.`wage` > `chief_id`.`wage`
```

I do not fully understand what needs to be written in `WHERE`, probably it is impossible

2. Try to select all chiefs, who have exactly one direct subordinate
   I can not find construction to get "exactly one direct subordinate"

   `SELECT` `id`, `office_id`, `name`, `SUM`(`wage`) `AS` `total_wage`
   `FROM` `person`
   `GROUP BY` `id`, `office_id`
   `ORDER BY`
   `total_wage` `DESC`

Probably like this?

3. Select all offices sorted by total wage of people in it, descending.
   I understand that I need to use `DESC`, how can I count 'sorted by total wage of people in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the answers

1.question

```
select p1.* from person as p1, person as p2
where p1.chief_id = p2.id
and p1.wage<p2.wage
```

2. question

> ```
> select distinct p2.* from person as p1, person as p2
> where p1.chief_id = p2.id
> ```

or

```
 select p2.person_id from person as p1, person as p2
 where p1.chief_id = p2.id
 group by p2.person_id
```

3. question

> ```
> select office_id, sum(wage) from person
> group by office_id
> order by sum(wage)  desc
> ```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions would be:

1. You can use a inner join on chief_id and then you would have employee.wage  and his/her chief.wage in the same row, then you can select and compare
2. Search for the chief_id that only showed up once in the chief_id column, which means there is only one subordinate
3. You can try to use SUM to select and add all wages up by office_id

Hope these are helpful to you